# How to fix symbol __vdso_clock_gettime, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: gcc, centos, conda, glibc, libc

when I try to fix the problem `/lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found` in `CentOS 6` system by install latest `glibc` version to my home directory, I found my computer crashed.

```
$ conda
/public/home/liuxs/anaconda3/bin/python: relocation error: /lib64/librt.so.1: symbol __vdso_clock_gettime, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
$ python
python: relocation error: /lib64/librt.so.1: symbol __vdso_clock_gettime, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

I try my best to remove all the thing I have done and google to fix this, I failed. I cannot understand the problem, how it occurs and which part should I focus -- `libc.so.6` or `librt.so.1`? Which is the key.

I have no root permission, so I cannot change the files for `lib`, `lib64` etc.

```
$ ls -l $(locate librt.so.1)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul  6  2017 /lib64/librt.so.1 -> librt-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jul  6  2017 /lib64/rtkaio/librt.so.1 -> librtkaio-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug  1  2017 /lib/i686/nosegneg/librt.so.1 -> librt-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug  1  2017 /lib/librt.so.1 -> librt-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Aug  1  2017 /lib/rtkaio/i686/nosegneg/librt.so.1 -> librtkaio-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Aug  1  2017 /lib/rtkaio/librt.so.1 -> librtkaio-2.12.so


$ ls -l $(locate libc.so.6)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Dec 25 13:51 /lib64/libc.so.6 -> /lib64/libc-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Aug  1  2017 /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Aug  1  2017 /lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.so
```

I also have these two files in `conda` directory, which can not be `locate`

```
$ ls -l $(find . -name "libc.so.6")
-rwxrwxr-x 1 liuxs liuxs 3985000 Jun 21  2017 ./lib/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxr-x 1 liuxs liuxs      14 May 10 19:26 ./pkgs/gcc_impl_linux-64-7.2.0-habb00fd_3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.2.so
lrwxrwxr-x 1 liuxs liuxs      14 Mar 28 12:06 ./x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.2.so
[liuxs@HPC-login anaconda3]$ ls -l $(find . -name "librt.so.1")
lrwxrwxr-x 1 liuxs liuxs 15 Mar 28 11:25 ./pkgs/gcc_impl_linux-64-7.2.0-habb00fd_3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/librt.so.1 -> librt-2.12.2.so
lrwxrwxr-x 1 liuxs liuxs 15 Mar 28 12:06 ./x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/librt.so.1 -> librt-2.12.2.so
```

I think maybe it's file in `anaconda3` make this error but I dont know how to locate the source of problem. And I dont know when I run `conda` or `python`, which `librt.so.1` and `libc.so.6` the commands use.

Hope someone can help me out of this.

Comment: You are trying to run a program that is fundamentally incompatible with the runtime of your CentOS 6 machine. You should find a pre-built binary that is suitable for CentOS 6, or if this is an open source project, build it yourself

Comment: Thanks. It is a open source, I will take a  try.

Answer (score -2):

I found how to fix this, the problem came from

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 liuxs liuxs 3985000 Jun 21  2017 ./lib/libc.so.6
```

I change its name fro backup, and the system is okay now. Even though I don't very understand why it works. But the interesting thing is **No matter where the file `libc.so.6` is, the system will give an error.** Maybe it's not a good answer, I modify its name from `./lib/libc.so.6` to `./lib/libc.so.6.bk` in case I need it latter.

Thanks comment from @nos.

> You are trying to run a program that is fundamentally incompatible
>   with the runtime of your CentOS 6 machine. You should find a pre-built
>   binary that is suitable for CentOS 6, or if this is an open source
>   project, build it yourself